# GAE DataStore python - fetch() vs run()

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I saw there are two methods for getting data from the datastore:
fetch() and run()
Regarding fetch the documentation says:
Note: You should rarely need to use this method; it is almost always better to use run() instead.

I don't understand the difference between the two.
I am new to GAE and Python, please help me understand.
Thanks

It says that run() is asynchronous which I don't understand cause unlike JavaScript, once you run the Python script for the site, the html is frozen, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run (with run) multiple datastore queries in parallel to improve latency. This has nothing to do with your resulting HTML. The resulting HTML should be the same.

Comment: The answer is in the documentation : When To Use Async Datastore Calls. My suggestion is to use the NDB API  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/

Answer (score 3):

Beginner's advice: until you appreciate the difference, stick with fetch().  There are many other things you probably ought to get comfortable with first before this subtle distinction will bother you.